# X = np.copy(X) ... Is this really useless?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, copy

I am currently looking at the sklearn source code in github and I have encountered a line that bugs me. It's [this one](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L599).

I understand the difference between copying by value and copying by reference (I guess the copy function from numpy is by value and x = y is by reference).

But clearly I don't understand the purpose of copying to itself the same variable as in

- X = np.copy(X)

Can anyone throw some light upon this?

Thank you very much

Comment: As the function makes changes to `X` and `X` is a mutable object it's copied to itself to prevent any changes outside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That softmax function offers to run inplace in order to save a duplication op, therefore overwriting the input X with the result of the softmax.

The copy is here to avoid changing the input in case it is needed elswhere.

`X = np.copy(X)` replaces the original reference with a reference to the copy which is safe to modify.

Answer (score 0):

How would you suspect that the function will look like if you didn't assigned it back to the variable it already defined.

```
def softmax(X, copy=True):
    """
    Calculate the softmax function.
    The softmax function is calculated by
    np.exp(X) / np.sum(np.exp(X), axis=1)
    This will cause overflow when large values are exponentiated.
    Hence the largest value in each row is subtracted from each data
    point to prevent this.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like, shape (M, N)
        Argument to the logistic function
    copy : bool, optional
        Copy X or not.
    Returns
    -------
    out : array, shape (M, N)
        Softmax function evaluated at every point in x
    """
    def _softmax(X):
        max_prob = np.max(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
        X -= max_prob
        np.exp(X, X)
        sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
        X /= sum_prob
        return X

    return _softmax(np.copy(X) if copy else X)
```

This makes the code less readable. 
Overwriting a local variable when preprocessing the variable is normally accepted as it makes readable code. Adding a second variable will make understanding the code harder. In my example I tried to create code that was as easy to understand without any duplication. But you cannot read this code serial anymore. You first need to read the last statement `_softmax(np.copy(X) if copy else X)` to understand how it is being used.

In performance this also introduces an additional call what you don't want in these low level functions.